# Extract 2 integers from a string in two variables respectively in c++

Tags: c++11

I am new in programming,, and I want to store 2 integers from a string and stores them in respective variables.

Comment: How do the string look like? What have you tried so far?

Comment: example you have a string "hello 5 hello 6" and I want to extract 5 in one variable and 6 in another variable,, please help me..

Comment: Is the string *always* in that format? Can the numbers be in different positions?

Comment: yes,, every time string was changed.. numbers or variables change their place..

Comment: Then you need to parse the string to see what each part is. It can be done by using e.g. [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) then use the stream to get each "word" from the string, and check if the string is a number or not (can be done with e.g. [`std::stoi`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol)).

Comment: #include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s("Somewhere down the road");
    istringstream iss(s);

    do
    {
        string sub;
        iss >> sub;
        cout << "Substring: " << sub << endl;
    } while (iss);

}

Comment: I am trying this. And it will give me 0 on output?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to use regex for this purpose.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <regex>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "string 5 another string 6";

    std::regex digit_regex("(\\d+)");

    auto digits_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), digit_regex);
    auto digits_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    std::cout << "Found "
              << std::distance(digits_begin, digits_end)
              << " digits \n";

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = digits_begin; i != digits_end; ++i) {
        std::smatch match = *i;
        std::string match_str = match.str();
        std::cout << "Found digit: " << match_str << std::endl;
    }          
}
```

Example output:

```
Found 2 digits 
Found digit: 5
Found digit: 6
```

Comment: To the OP, please [read this first](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/223634/what-is-meant-by-now-you-have-two-problems) before deciding to use regular expressions.